# Can't Send Base64 string To C# via AJAX

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I am simply sending a base64 string thru ajax to an aspx page with C# code behind. The string never makes it to the C#. It always comes out empty.

The ajax is being sent in the post request and all other form fields post fine.

My string looks like: `QmFzZSA2NCDigJQgTW96aWxsYSBEZXZlbG9wZXIgTmV0d29yaw==`

The method that sends the string to c# code behind is:

```
string signature = Request.Form.Get("newsig");
var pdfContents = PDFHelper.GeneratePDF(pdfPath, formFieldMap, signature);
```

The code behind:

```
string base64image = sig;
//  Convert base64string to bytes array
var newbytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64image);
```

Sometimes the base64 string is long - could this be the issue? Is there a better way of handling base64 strings in c#?

UPDATE: my ajax post method:

```
    var localbase64string = localStorage["signature"];
    var b64 = localbase64string.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");

    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    formData.append( 'newsig', b64);

    var sendPost = 'http://xxx.xx/this.aspx';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        timeout: 50000,
        url: sendPost,
        success: function(data){
            alert('Sent!');
            window.location.href = './../mainmenu.html';

       }, error:function (){  
                    alert("something went wrong!");
        }

    });
```

Comment: Where is your ajax code?

Comment: Didn't think it was necessary since the form posts just fine. Including the base64 string which I have used before. I can see the response is getting the string but its posting as null every time.

Comment: which method of ajax being used to send data , POST or GET, if it is get it will not be form but will be a part of query string  ?

Comment: @Dreamweaver i just updated my Initial Post with my ajax call. Its a simple post of form data coming from an html page to a aspx page with c# codebehind. All other data posts with no problem but base64 string is always empty.

Comment: replace b64 with a small text like 'dummy' and see if you get it at the server side. if yes, then something is wrong with b64. (maximum posted byte size etc.) if no, something is wrong with the post mechanism/page method etc. and also, try seeing in Fiddler, the request/response.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to check what content you're sending is to use **Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result** in your C# receiving method.

Here's an example I put together quick:

**C#:**

```
public IHttpActionResult PostB64Test(string one, string two)
    {
        string b64 = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;            
        return Ok();
    }
```

**JS:**

```
// here's an example url. I'm adding the base64 string to the POST body,
// and the other parameters in the query string.

 var url = '/api/xxx/b64/?one=' +1 +'&two=' +2 +'';

 var b64 = ""; // your base64 string e.g., "9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAg..."
 $http.post(url, { b64: b64 });
```